# How do you set the value of a variable to the value of an arrays slot defined by another variable(see code) in Batch

Tags: batch-file

in a larger program that I am attempting to create in batch format it is important that I learn how to set a variables value to that of an arrays value as determined by the number of another variable if it is possible in a simple .bat file. my current code for the testing file reads as

```
    set a[1]=1
    set a[0]=10000
    set c=0
    set b=%a[%%c]% 
    echo %b%
```

all this returns is:
**ECHO is off**
I need it to return:
**10000** so I can then use similar code

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    set Goblin[0]=5
    set Goblin[1]=20
    set Goblin[2]=7
    set Goblin[3]=Goblin

    set Zombie[0]=7
    set Zombie[1]=15
    set Zombie[2]=3
    set Zombie[3]=Zombie

    set Skeleton[0]=3
    set Skeleton[1]=11
    set Skeleton[2]=10
    set Skeleton[3]=Skeleton

    set Orc[0]=7
    set Orc[1]=25
    set Orc[2]=0
    set Orc[3]=Orc

    set Acrobat[0]=4
    set Acrobat[1]=15
    set Acrobat[2]=80
    set Acrobat[3]=Acrobat

    set PossibleEnemies[0]=!Goblin!
    set PossibleEnemies[1]=!Zombie!
    set PossibleEnemies[2]=!Skeleton!
    set PossibleEnemies[3]=!Orc!
    set PossibleEnemies[4]=!Acrobat!

    set /a Enemy1=%random% %%5
    set /a Enemy2=%random% %%5

    set /a Enemy1.MaximumHealth=%PossibleEnemies[Enemy1[1]]%
    set /a Enemy2.MaximumHealth=%PossibleEnemies[Enemy2[1]]%
    set /a Enemy1.Damage=%PossibleEnemies[Enemy1[0]]%
    set /a Enemy2.Damage=%PossibleEnemies[Enemy2[0]]%
    set /a Enemy1.Dodge=%PossibleEnemies[Enemy1[2]]%
    set /a Enemy2.Dodge=%PossibleEnemies[Enemy2[2]]%
    set Enemy1.Name=%PossibleEnemies[Enemy1[3]]%
    set Enemy2.Name=%PossibleEnemies[Enemy2[3]]%
```

to randomize which enemy you are fighting(you fight two at once).
I have also tried

```
    set a[1]=1
    set a[0]=10000
    set c=0
    set b=%a[%c%]% 
    echo %b%
```

and

```
    set a[1]=1
    set a[0]=10000
    set c=0
    set b=%a[!c!]% 
    echo %b%
```

as well as

```
    set a[1]=1
    set a[0]=10000
    set c=0
    set b=%a[c]% 
    echo %b%
```

to no avail

Comment: Use `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion"` as first command after the `@ECHO OFF` and then try `!a[%c%]!` in the scripts.

Comment: I have that in there I dont know if I listed it

Comment: [short how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) (towards the end of my answer) and [a bit more in-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script) (get yourself a big cup of coffee before visiting)

Comment: thx stephan but what about arrays in arrays nested with variables
sample code

```
    a[1]=%b%
    b[1]=2
    c=1
    d=a[c[1]]
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are other tricks that can do this, but basic method would be this:

```
@ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set a[1]=1
    set a[0]=10000
    set c=0
    set b=!a[%c%]!
    echo %b%
```

**EDIT:**
Stephan's comment had a link that included the trick I couldn't remember, but I knew it used `CALL` (**NOTE: Call cost time and can slow a script down.**):

```
@ECHO OFF
    set a[1]=1
    set a[0]=10000
    set c=0
    CALL SET b=%%a[%c%]%%
    echo %b%
```

Comment: wait I found something, might edit the question slightly in the big code I have arrays inside of the main array and I am finding the proper array to use, would this cause problems? if so how should I fix it?

Comment: well I tested it on the main program, and I got the same results I have been getting so I am going to assume that is a yes :/

Comment: @DNABuster, you might be able to merge both tricks that I now have in the answer to get an array element pointed to by an array element.  Or you might save the first element to a variable and then use that variable to get the content of the other array's element.

Comment: yeah thats a good fix(second one)

Comment: When you run what?

Comment: when I echo the variables it doesnt print, fix?

Comment: I had meant my full program, and it was because of the /a for some reason

Answer (score 1):

There are no arrays in `cmd/batch`. The one and only variable type is STRING (although Lists and Arrays can be simulated to a certain degree). I therefore would change from arrays (independent variables for each element) to lists (one variable containing all elements) and put all "array/list stuff handling" into a subroutine, making it easy in the main code to get a certain element:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM define readable names for indexes (for more readable code later)
set "MaxHealth=2"
set "Damage=1"
set "Dodge=3"
set "Name=4"
set "Goblin=1"
set "Zombie=2"
set "Skeleton=3"
set "Orc=4"
set "Acrobat=5"

REM define a list of properties for each creature
set "_Goblin=5,20,7,little Goblin"
set "_Zombie=7,15,3,angry Zombie"
set "_Skeleton=3,11,10,bony Skeleton"
set "_Orc=7,25,0,furious Orc"
set "_Acrobat=4,15,80,fast Acrobat"

REM define a list of all creatures
set "PossibleEnemies=Goblin,Zombie,Skeleton,Orc,Acrobat"

set /a Enemy1=%random% %%5
set /a Enemy2=%random% %%5

REM get properties
call :GetProperty %Enemy1% Name Enemy1
call :GetProperty %Enemy2% Name Enemy2
call :GetProperty %Enemy1% MaxHealth Enemy1
call :GetProperty %Enemy2% MaxHealth Enemy2
call :GetProperty %Enemy1% Damage Enemy1
call :GetProperty %Enemy2% Damage Enemy2
call :GetProperty %Enemy1% Dodge Enemy1
call :GetProperty %Enemy2% Dodge Enemy2

echo You fight against:
set Enemy
goto :eof

:GetProperty Type Property VarName  ; resulting variable = [VarName].[Property]
echo DBG: EnemyType=%1
echo DBG: Property=%2
for /f "tokens=%1 delims=," %%a in ("%PossibleEnemies%") do set "Type=%%a"
echo DBG: Type=%Type%
echo DBG: ReturnVar=%3.%2
set "opt=tokens=!%2! delims=," & REM not possible to use delayed expansion in for /f "[options]"
for /f "%opt%" %%a in ("!_%Type%!") do set "%3.%2=%%a"
echo DBG: Returnval=!%3.%2!
echo DBG: -----
goto :of
```

Example output (without the `DBG` lines):

```
You fight against:
Enemy1=3
Enemy1.Damage=3
Enemy1.Dodge=10
Enemy1.MaxHealth=11
Enemy1.Name=bony Skeleton
Enemy2=1
Enemy2.Damage=5
Enemy2.Dodge=7
Enemy2.MaxHealth=20
Enemy2.Name=little Goblin
```

If you want, you can put the `REM get properties` (all those `call ...`lines) into another subroutine for even more readable main code.

**To answer your actual question:** you need one layer of expansion per depth-layer. You have a variable containing a variable containing a variable, so you need three layers of parsing (the original layer plus two more. One more layer is usually achieved by delayed expansion; three layers are a bit more complicated: use `call` for an additional layer. The innermost variable is used "as usual" `%c%` for the next layer you have to double each `%`, as one `%` gets consumed by the additional layer of parsing (the second `call`), the same is true for the outermost (third) layer (the first `call`), resulting in *four* `%`, because each layer of parsing halves them:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set a[2]=1000
set b[1]=2
set c=1
call call set d=%%%%a[%%b[%c%]%%]%%%%
echo %d%
```

result: `1000`

**Some words on efficiency:**

As @Darin already mentioned, `call` is slow (because it creates another instance of `cmd`. Of course `call call` is even slower. Take a look at the times the three loops take (an empty loop, a "call-call" loop and a loop using another loop to force another layer of parsing):

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set a[2]=1000
set b[1]=2
set c=1

echo start empty loop %time%
for /l %%i in (1,1,10000) do (
  REM
)
echo start call-call %time%
for /l %%i in (1,1,10000) do (
  call call set d=%%%%a[%%b[%c%]%%]%%%%
)
echo (proof it worked: %d%)
echo start speed-optimized %time%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%i in (1,1,10000) do (
    for %%j in (!b[%c%]!) do set "x=!a[%%j]!"
)
echo (proof it worked: %x%)
endlocal
echo End %time%
```

Output:

```
start empty loop 16:20:49,05
start call-call 16:20:49,06
(proof it worked: 1000)
start speed-optimized 16:21:02,51
(proof it worked: 1000)
End 16:21:03,06
```

(~0.1 seconds / ~12 seconds / ~ 0,6 seconds) - YMMV depending on hardware and processor load. Ok, it takes 10000 iterations to get to those numbers, but nevertheless - its a factor of ~20)

Comment: Just now read answer and I had no idea that you could `call call set`, that is a neat trick!

Comment: @Darin: yes, but it surely comes at a cost - see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using arrays was a mistake, I believe this could be because if you use them like a[0] then it names the variable a[0] instead of making an array. So I ended up finding out that there is a much better solution(for my problem at least).

```
call set PossibleEnemies.Name.0=Goblin
call set PossibleEnemies.Name.1=Zombie
call set PossibleEnemies.Name.2=Skeleton
call set PossibleEnemies.Name.3=Orc
call set PossibleEnemies.Name.4=Acrobat

call set PossibleEnemies.Damage.0=5
call set PossibleEnemies.Damage.1=3
call set PossibleEnemies.Damage.2=3
call set PossibleEnemies.Damage.3=7
call set PossibleEnemies.Damage.4=4

call set PossibleEnemies.Health.0=20
call set PossibleEnemies.Health.1=15
call set PossibleEnemies.Health.2=11
call set PossibleEnemies.Health.3=25
call set PossibleEnemies.Health.4=15

call set PossibleEnemies.Dodge.0=7
call set PossibleEnemies.Dodge.1=3
call set PossibleEnemies.Dodge.2=10
call set PossibleEnemies.Dodge.3=0
call set PossibleEnemies.Dodge.4=80

:EnemySetup1
set /a Enemy1.Num=%random% %%5
set /a Enemy2.Num=%random% %%5
goto EnemySetup2

:EnemySetup2
call set "Enemy1.MaximumHealth=!PossibleEnemies.Health.%Enemy1.Num%!"
call set "Enemy2.MaximumHealth=!PossibleEnemies.Health.%Enemy2.Num%!"
call set "Enemy1.Health=!PossibleEnemies.Health.%Enemy1.Num%!"
call set "Enemy2.Health=!PossibleEnemies.Health.%Enemy2.Num%!"
call set "Enemy1.Damage=!PossibleEnemies.Damage.%Enemy1.Num%!"
call set "Enemy2.Damage=!PossibleEnemies.Damage.%Enemy2.Num%!"
call set "Enemy1.Dodge=!PossibleEnemies.Health.%Enemy1.Num%!"
call set "Enemy2.Dodge=!PossibleEnemies.Dodge.%Enemy2.Num%!"
call set Enemy1.Name=!PossibleEnemies.Name.%Enemy1.Num%!
call set Enemy2.Name=!PossibleEnemies.Name.%Enemy2.Num%!
```

Yeah so if you need to use arrays there will probably be a better option. For me it was just using nested variables. So if you are a beginner I would suggest avoiding variables AT ALL COSTS!

Comment: also sometimes when I kill an enemy I instantly die, and I cant figure out why.